# Playing audio file in background (multitasking)

Tags: iphone, multithreading, xcode, audio

I have searched for many web sites in order to play my audio file even the home button on iPhone is pressed. And I have come up with the following:

```
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"forest" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSData *sampleData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSError *audioError = nil;

av = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:sampleData error:&audioError];
[sampleData release];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
[av play];
```

Then an error msg comes up:

> 'AVAudioSession' undeclared (first use in this function)

Can anyone explain why this error is shown??

Edit:
I have the followings as well:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Comment: Did you include the required header files amd frameworks?

Comment: You might have included added `#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h> #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`. But I guess u could not have included the framework to the project.

Comment: I believe I have added the framework as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you have included AVFoundation framework and using the correct includes on your code.

Comment: I have done:
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

Comment: Have you included AVFoundation in your XCode project. If you have not included the framework, importing the header file will not help.

Comment: how about #import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>

Comment: omg, well spotted.
And another problem is that: the iPhone simulator do not support multithreading!
Thank you so much  "the.evangelist"